# Can I create a tailable cursor for a query in mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream, mongoose

Using mongo and mongoose in node, I can create a stream from a capped collection like this:

```
@stream = Post.find().tailable().stream()
```

But can I do it with a query like this as well?:

```
@stream = Post.find({tagged:true}).tailable().stream()
```

When I try to run the above code, I get the error

```
MongoError: tailable cursor requested on non capped collection
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible according to the docs - search for it here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/query.html

Comment: Try it with a capped schema: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#capped

Comment: Thanks, I read through that page, but I can't find an example where it has a query with actual options/filters. so Posts is already a capped collection. Do you have any idea why the 2nd line would throw the error, when the first one does not?

Comment: Probably because if you want it `tailable` it needs to be `capped` - but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hm.. thanks for pointing this out. Seems like maybe I did not the collection to be capped correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your Post schema:

```
var postSchema = new Schema({..}, { capped: 1024 });
```